# Querying 2 Entities With Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, nosql

I have 2 diferent Entities:

- **USER**:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class UserMW {

      @Id
      private Long id;

      private String name;

      private Long score;
      ...
  }
  ```
- **USER_CHALLENGE**

  ```
  @Entity
  public class UserChallengeMW {

      @Id
      private Long id;

      @Index
      private Ref<UserMW> user;

      @Index
      @Load
      private Ref<ChallengeMW> challenge;
  }
  ```

I want to be able to get one ChallengeMW object and query all users which have done this ChallengeMW. So far it's pretty simple. I just need to query USER_CHALLENGE filtering by "Ref challenge". Something like this:

```
ofy().load().type(UserChallengeMW.class).filter("challenge", challengeRef).list();
```

**The problem is**, I want to order it according to the property "***score***" into USER entity. Any idea about what is the correct way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no joins in the datastore. Either denormalize the 'score' into the `UserChallengeMW` object or query for all the data and sort it in memory.

Comment: That's sad. Anyway, I'll wait for a day more to see if anyone comes with a better solution. If it doesn't happen I'll marque this answer as correct.